# Apache Camel - Marshalling within Rest DSL to Json

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to process a csv file using the Rest DSL in Camel.

I'm getting some odd behaviour when I split the CSV and Marshall to a JSON. Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class
ProcessHandler extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    protected void defineRoute() throws Exception {

        DataFormat csv = new BindyCsvDataFormat(CsvModel.class);

        rest("/")
                .post().produces("application/json")
                .route()

                .unmarshal(csv)
                .split(body()).parallelProcessing().streaming()
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
                .filter().jsonpath("$[?(@.counter==3)]")
                .log("${body}")
```

However I get the error message: `Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: byte[] with value [CsvModel(....`

However if I edit the route as follows:

```
@Component
public class
ProcessHandler extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    protected void defineRoute() throws Exception {

        DataFormat csv = new BindyCsvDataFormat(CsvModel.class);

        rest("/")
                .post().produces("application/json")
                .route()

                .unmarshal(csv)
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
                .split(body()).parallelProcessing().streaming()
                //.filter().jsonpath("$[?(@.counter==3)]")
                .log("${body}")
```

It works ok.

However then I'm obviously not able to process my message correctly as it's marshalled to byte representation. The route also works fine if it's not using the Rest DSL, so I'm assuming the issue is with the http response. If I try the following:

```
@Component
public class
ProcessHandler extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    protected void defineRoute() throws Exception {

        DataFormat csv = new BindyCsvDataFormat(CsvModel.class);

        rest("/")
                .post().produces("application/json")
                .route()

                .unmarshal(csv)
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)

                .split(body()).parallelProcessing().streaming()
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
                .filter().jsonpath("$[?(@.counter==3)]")
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
                .log("${body}")
```

I get the same error. Is it possible to normalise the format, make some processing steps and then return a Json? Am I going wrong somewhere - I would appreciate understanding why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be more easy and hence comprehensible if you implement an aggregation strategy with your filtering within instead of using JsonPath.

Indeed, the `split()` methid if used by default will not give the results you are expecting

Here is an example :

```
@Component
public class ProcessHandler extends RouteBuilder {

            @Override
            protected void defineRoute() throws Exception {

            DataFormat csv = new BindyCsvDataFormat(CsvModel.class);

            rest("/")
                    .post().produces("application/json")
                         .route()
                              .unmarshal(csv)
                              .split().method(ItemsSplittingStrategy.class, "splitItems")
                                  .parallelProcessing()
                                  .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
                              .end()
                    .to("file:/file.json");
    }
}
```

And in your `ItemsSplittingStrategy` class, do you filtering. You can find a simple, explicit example [here](https://github.com/Talend/apache-camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/SplitterPojoTest.java#L69)

Also i invite you to check all the features that can be use for splitter and aggregator and their combinaison.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful and works much better. I'm a little confused as to why the `filter` EIP doesn't work after the `splitter` EIP. For example when I add `.filter().jsonpath("$[?(@.counter==3)]")` it now doesn't have an issue with the encoding, but doesn't appear to actually filter the messages..?

Comment: This has to do with type of output in the exchange. In your code you are unmarshaling the JSON then after applying the filter with jsonPath. I would do the filtering before unmarshlling the JSON.

Comment: Thanks. Given that the data is pretty large, I'd rather `split` then `stream` messages to avoid creating a large memory overhead. Do you know of any work arounds? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's a good thing to use a parallel processing. Also you can include in your strategy a batching system to chunk data.